# create uninitialized object in pcl

Tags: c#, portable-class-library

Is there any way to create uninitialized objects in a portable class library?

In standard .NET Framework this can be done using [FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatterservices.getuninitializedobject%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

However this Class+Namespace is not available in the PCL version of mscorlib. Is there an alternative i am not aware of?

Comment: [`Activator.CreateInstance`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx) is available in a number of overloads, where at least some are available in PCL. Would that meet your requirements? In what PCL scenario would you use `FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject` anyway? Correct me if I am wrong, but this method would mainly be relevant to binary serialization, right? And binary serialization is unavailable in PCL.

Comment: @AndersGustafsson I know. i'm aware of activator ofc. However Activator always attempts to use constructors. if none is present an exception is thrown. In my case i need an instance of an object regardless of a default constructor. However i'm using DI now to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for the people who come here from google and are asking because they are working with xamarin:

## Update:

If the pcl project is set to netstandard 2.0, FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject will be available.

[.Net Api reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatterservices.getuninitializedobject?view=netstandard-2.0#System_Runtime_Serialization_FormatterServices_GetUninitializedObject_System_Type_)

check this to see if it is compatible with your runtime: https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions.md#net-standard-versions

## Old answer where no .netstandard library is possible:

usage in pcl:

```
DependencyService.Get<IObjectFactory>().CreateUninitialized(typeof(MyType));
```

pcl definition:

```
public interface IObjectFactory
{
    object CreateUninitialized(Type type);
}
```

android:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(ObjectFactory))]
namespace YOURNAMESPACE
{
    public class ObjectFactory : IObjectFactory
    {
        public object CreateUninitialized(Type type)
        {
            return FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(type);
        }
    }
}
```

ios:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(ObjectFactory))]
namespace YOURNAMESPACE
{
    public class ObjectFactory : IObjectFactory
    {
        public object CreateUninitialized(Type type)
        {
            return FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(type);
        }
    }
}
```

WP:

> Same method doesnt work here yet. possibly because my project is WP8.1
> Silverlight. I'll update once i have a reason to change project type and implement it.